# Question about conservative vector field and a statement in Wolfram Mathworld

Tags: calculus, integration, vector-spaces, vector-analysis, vector-fields

In this reference https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LineIntegral.html in expression (7) we have that if $F(.)$ is a conservative vector field then "a Cartesian path can therefore be chosen between starting and ending point to give

$$ \int_{(a,b,c)}^{(x,y,z)} F_1(x)dx+F_2(y)dy+F_3(z)dz=\int_{(a,b,c)}^{(x,b,c)} F(x)dx+ \int_{(x,b,c)}^{(x,y,c)}F(y)dy+ \int_{(x,y,c)}^{(x,y,z)}F(z)dz $$

My questions are:

1. which "ending point" is meant here, what are $(x,y,z)$ at the upper bound?
2. what is the name of this result, so that I can search more, for the intuition and formal proof? (Of course happy to get some ideas on those directly here!)

Thanks!

Comment: If you patiently read the Wikipedia article about [Line integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral) the two questions will answer themselves.

Comment: Thanks nonetheless, the reference to the conservative vector field Wiki article that d_b gave below turned out to be helpful. I understand that reading patiently Wiki helps, it is just that we are all different, I have to do for the first time in my life with vector fields (for one specific application in my own field which is very far from physics) and it is too much to digest all of a sudden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $(x, y, z)$ is an arbitrary point in three-dimensional space
2. This is a straightforward consequence of that fact that the line integral of a conservative vector field is path-independent, so we can calculate along any path we wish. You could consider this as the definition of a conservative vector field, so it doesn't require a proof. (If you want to use one of the other equivalent definitions, showing path independence is not difficult. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field).)